# Kubernetes - Affinity Cookie - requests are not coming back to the same pod replica

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod

I was looking for how to use cookie affinity in GKE. and I successfully implemented it (thanks to this question: [Problems configuring Ingress with cookie affinity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57868848/problems-configuring-ingress-with-cookie-affinity)) and now I can see that I am received GCLB Cookie, but for some reason, requests are not coming back to the same pod replica

I've created a YAML with the following:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-bsc-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      purpose: bsc-config-demo
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        purpose: bsc-config-demo
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello-app-container
        image: gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0
---
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: my-bsc-backendconfig
spec:
  timeoutSec: 40
  connectionDraining:
    drainingTimeoutSec: 60
  sessionAffinity:
    affinityType: "GENERATED_COOKIE"
    affinityCookieTtlSec: 50
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-bsc-service
  labels:
    purpose: bsc-config-demo
  annotations:
    beta.cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"ports": {"80":"my-bsc-backendconfig"}}'
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    purpose: bsc-config-demo
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-bsc-ingress
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: my-bsc-service
    servicePort: 80
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: my-bsc-service
          servicePort: 80
---
```

What might be causing such an issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is this, from GCP HTTP(S) Load Balancers [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/#firewall_rules):

> You must create a firewall rule that allows traffic from
>   130.211.0.0/22 and 35.191.0.0/16 to reach your instances. These are IP address ranges that the load balancer uses to connect to backend
>   instances.

Your users do not connect to the backends directly, but through these "proxies", so the session affinity happens, but not as you want. In fact, if you are using GCLB, you should avoid session affinity.

Comment: This is true, but allowing the source IP ranges from GCLB don't warranty you that requests from the same client go to the same pod every time the client has a new request. The ranges are only needed to allow `livenessProbe` and `readynessProbe`

Comment: My point is that the requests do not come from users' IP addresses, but these Load Balancer IP ranges, so session affinity can't happen.

Comment: Yes, your point is clear and is correct that is needed to allow traffic from GCLB, but he is asking because the traffic is not going to the "same pod replica" it means that the traffic passing from the GCLB but is not applying the session affinity properly

Answer (score 1):

The affinity is working, just not the way you would expect. The affinity is currently happening between the GCP LB and it's backend (the node, not the pod). Once traffic reaches your node, the service then forwards the request to a pod. Since the service does not have affinity, it chooses a pod essentially at random. There are two ways to make this work.

1. Use [container native load balancing using network endpoint groups](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/container-native-load-balancing). This will result in the pods acting as backends to the Load Balancer so the cookie affinity should stick.
2. Leave the Ingress as is, configure your NodePort service with [`spec.sessionAffinity`](https://gist.github.com/fjudith/e8acc791f015adf6fd47e5ad7be736cb). On GKE, only supports `clientIP` as the value for this field. The next step is to ensure that the client IP is actually used correctly, add the `spec.externalTrafficPolicy: Local` field.

Alternately, you can use Nginx ingress which does not cause 2 layer load balancing like the GCP ingress does so tha affinity is more direct but is not supported by Google support.

Answer (score 0):

I have to confront the same problem and the last layer of balancing the traffic is `kubeproxy`, this proxy doesn't support session affinity at all.

To solve the problem you have to use a different ingress controller to replace `kubeproxy` with a proxy service that supports session affinity, in my case I use Nginx. You have some good examples of how to implement it on the GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs), basic usage [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/basic-usage.md) and also you can use annotations to configure the Nginx depending on each ingress needs, the complete list of annotations [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md).